How to compute $\displaystyle\int_{i\infty+1}^1\frac{e^{i2(n+1)x}}{\sin(x)}\, \mathrm dx$
I need to solve
$$\int_{i\infty+1}^1\frac{e^{i2(n+1)x}}{\sin(x)}\, \mathrm dx$$
which appears in the closed form of
$$\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{e^{i2k}}{2k+1}.$$
By the looks of the integrand, Euler's identity + Chebyshev polynomials might be helpful since
$$\frac{e^{i2(n+1)x}}{\sin(x)}=\frac{\cos[2(n+1)x]}{\sin x}+i\frac{\sin[2(n+1)x]}{\sin x}$$
Maybe even Residue Theorem could be useful.

Is your integration path the vertical half-line $\Re(z)=1$ and $\Im(z) \ge 0$ ? In this case, you should replace $x$ by $1+ix, \ x \ge 0$.

Actually, yes, as long as $c$ satisfies $\underset{x\to i\infty+c}{\lim} e^{i(2n+1)x}=0$ for $n\geq 0$, I guess you can take any lower bound of the form $i\infty+c$. This condition is for convenience purposes.
